# How to show name of choice elements in StarUML?

Tags: uml, staruml, state-diagram

I'am creating an statechart diagram in StarUML and I want to show the name of choice elements in the diagram, but I don't know how to do it without adding a text annotation.

[image]

Do you know if it is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(...)

Showing names of control nodes (including decision, merge, ...) diagram is not supported. It was never supported in previous versions, even in V1. Typically just show the guards of the control flows connected to the decision node, instead of showing the name of decision node. At this time, we recommend to use "Text" or "Note" annotation.
(...)

Thanks,
StarUML Team

This was the answer about the same question in this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/staruml/E-l4JeRR4Qo). Take a look.

Comment: Taken from another answer from the same forum. "OK. I understand what you expect. However, we strongly recommend to use "guard" property of "Control Flow" instead of using "name" of "Decision Node". Please refers to: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#decision-node"

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Victor, I just add Text Element inside the Choice Element.

[image]